# Duplica etiqueta a por un bucle

Tags: php

Tengo un tema que no le encuentro la vuelta, en un menú de navegación, tengo puesto etiquetas `a` según los permisos que tenga los usuarios. No se que estoy haciendo mal ya que duplica las etiquetas, si me pudieran orientar.

tengo este array:

```
$PermisosAdm = ['sd22412','ef24141', 'rt4422', 'se33222'];
```

donde guardo los usuarios con permisos de administrador, y donde le digo:

```
 for ($i=0; $i < count($PermisosAdm) ;$i++) {
 if($nombre == $PermisosAdm[$i]) {
 echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos">'.$icono_adm.'</i><a href="../../Administrador/adminYPF/">Administrador</a></span>';
 echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos">'.$icono_vs.'<a href="../../Sistemas/'.$EventNOC.'/">Visualizador</a></span>';
  }
 };
```

para mostrar etiquetas que solo quiero que vean los usuarios admin. Y los que no tienen esos permisos, digo:

```
 for ($q=0; $q < count($PermisosAdm); $q ++){
 if ($nombre != $PermisosAdm[$q]){
 echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos">'.$icono_dashboard.'<a href="../dashboard_usuarios/Gnoc.php">Home</a></span>';
 echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos_d">'.$icono_adm.'<a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Administrador</a></span>';
 echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos_d">'.$icono_vs.'<a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Visualizador</a></span>';
    }
 }
```

Las etiquetas `a` se deshabilitan para que no puedan acceder, el tema es el siguiente, por el orden que esta el usuario en el array, el primero ve todo perfecto, pero los demás se duplican las etiquetas `a`

Algún consejo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que recorres dos veces el arreglo `$PermisosAdm`

- La primera para saber si SI es admin (*supongamos que no*).
- La segunda para saber si NO es admin. Acá esta el problema, por cada admin que hay en el arreglo se va a generar el menú.

#### Solución:

Recorre el arreglo una sola vez y despues de que hayas averiguado es ES o NO admin, genera el menú.

##### Ejemplo:

```php
$esAdmin = in_array($nombre, $PermisosAdm);
if($esAdmin) {
    echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos">'.$icono_adm.'</i><a href="../../Administrador/adminYPF/">Administrador</a></span>';
    echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos">'.$icono_vs.'<a href="../../Sistemas/'.$EventNOC.'/">Visualizador</a></span>';
} else {
    echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos">'.$icono_dashboard.'<a href="../dashboard_usuarios/Gnoc.php">Home</a></span>';
    echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos_d">'.$icono_adm.'<a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Administrador</a></span>';
    echo '<span class="offcanvas-textos_d">'.$icono_vs.'<a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Visualizador</a></span>';
}
```

Comment: Wow, muchas gracias, la verdad era lo que necesitaba, y no lograba darme cuenta! apenas me deje, te doy como valida tu respuesta!